# GoogleSheet: IMPORTXML error, resource at url not found?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, xpathquery

What you will see from images below is that A1 is filled with random number which generated from the script. The number will change randomly every-time cursor is moved, it's used in method for "forcing update the XML data" in Google Sheets.

[image: Picture 1]

as we can see from the 1st picture, the IMPORTXML worked like charm, using `=IMPORTXML("Link" &A1(which is the random number, that is needed to update the data), "//target content")` recipe

Well, it worked out for the 1st link, but not really for the second one, in the 1st image, B2 is using the last link, and it shows `1736.5` as the value, that is showing fine without using `&A1` code

[image: Picture 2]

After adding &A1 to the formula, it gives error `#N/A` and `Resource at url not found` as the error detail.

I already tried to use another cell with calculated numbers(more than A1 or less than), still gives me that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

If you look closely to the second URL you will notice it finishes with an `=` sign. In URLs this symbol is used to express key values pairs. Using your refresh trick, in this case, you are specifying to the server to look for a resource that actually doesn't exist. Hence the `IMPORTXML` error. Just put the generated URL in the browser to see the result.

Try to put another random parameter in the URL that will cause to refresh the page without causing a 404 HTTP error.

For example:

```
https://www.cnbc.com/quotes/?symbol=XAU=&x=0
```

Won't cause any error and will give the desired result.

Comment: wow, that is very unexpected, the problem is the URL itself, mindblowing answer. thank you very much, now the formula is just purfect.

Comment: but it confusing me at some point, where without `&$A$1` in the formula, it parsed just fine without `&x=0`

Comment: I don't know exactly what the parameter is. But I assume it works since the `XAU` value it's just not specified.

Comment: its okay, just hoping that someday this mystery got revealed.